# If there exists $\alpha$ where $0<\alpha\leq\|x+y\|$, does there exist $\beta$ where $\|x\|+\|y\|\leq\beta\|x+y\|$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

If there exists $\alpha$ where $0<\alpha\leq\|x+y\|$, does there exist $\beta$ where $\|x\|+\|y\|\leq\beta\|x+y\|$ for some $\beta$ dependent on $\alpha$?  Basically, I'd like to rebound the triangle inequality when we know that $\|x+y\|$ is bounded away from $0$.  I know that if we are not bounded away from zero, we have an issue.  For example, if $x=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ and $y=-x$, we have
$$
0=\|x+y\|\leq\|x\|+\|y\|\nleq\beta\|x+y\|=0
$$
for any $\beta \geq0$.  However, if we are bounded away from zero, I thought there may be a chance.  In case it helps, we can assume we're in an inner product space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. $y=x+\epsilon$ where $||\epsilon||=\alpha$ is a small quantity. We can make $x$ and $y$ arbitrarily large while keeping the $||x+y||$ constant

Comment: Ah, you're right.  If we set $y=-x+\epsilon$ where $\|\epsilon\|=\alpha$, then $\|x+y\|=\|\epsilon\|=\alpha$.  This means that $\beta\|x+y\|=\beta \alpha$.  However, if we look at $\|x\|+\|y\|=\|x\|+\|-x+\epsilon\|$, we can just drive $\|x\|\rightarrow\infty$, which pushes $\|x\|+\|y\|\rightarrow\infty$, which can't be bounded by $\beta\alpha$.